# Pagination of horizontal / wide tables in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, pagination

There are a lot of solutions for the pagination of tables on websites. The problem is that non of these offer a solution for horizontal - very wide - tables.

I have an attendance list for students (vertical) for a lot of school days (horizontal). Due to the number of days the list needs to be scrolled horizontally a lot and cannot be printed correctly since even in lanscape mode the text is cut off.

Is there a way for a column-wise pagination of tables by repeating the first column with the name of the students and flipping through the dates?

```
<tr><th>Names</th><th>1.01.2019</th><th>2.01.2019</th><th>2.01.2019</th><th>...</th><th>29.04.2019</th></tr>
<tr><td>Bilbo Beutlin<td><td>present</td><td>absent</td><td>present</td><td>...</td><td>present</td></tr>
...
```

Comment: I think programs like Excel and Numbers offer that functionality when printing, so the easiest solution might be to copy>paste the table to Excel. Do you want to program a solution yourself in Javascript? Then you'll need to generate the table dynamically based on student data. Have you tried that?

Comment: Since there are already solutions for vertical pagination of tables as Javascript available I hoped I missed a version where horizontal pagination is also possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not fit enought in Javascript to do something like that myself.

Comment: But, to get an answer here, you'll need to post some of your code and show what you tried to solve the problem. In general, people won't code your entire solution for you.